# Tab Switch Buttons are not working in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, game-development

When I click the buttons for switching tabs the game doesn't switch and remains on the click tab. I've tried most things to troubleshoot (including restarting the project and following the tutorial) but whenever I get back to this point there's some weird error that stops the tab buttons from functioning.

If my explanation was unclear here is what the buttons are meant to do (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SnM725WeKsI&list=PLGSUBi8nI9v907UWXEXAi2wTtfUcBip1s&index=21 - **(Ep 3.1) Upgrade Tabs (Organization) - Unity C# Idle Game Tutorial Series [2021 Edition]**)

Additionally here's a link to the github for you to review the code (Scripts), and two short videos showing the problem in the Unity Editor:

Google Drive: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1mRdP_5RyeN8PYvUBpRovK3Q4zMF7PxNv?usp=sharing
Github: https://github.com/sakugaxl/MonarchMobile-v0.0.1-Repo

I'm quite new to C# as well.

I believe the problem comes from the UpgradeLists GameObject.

[Full Hierarchy] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lW0A6.png)

Scripts GameObjects have c# scripts of the same name attached to them from the project window.

I've tried Debugging (although, I think I'm doing it wrong) and I've tried restarting/redoing.

Comment: are you using the new input system, and did you update event system to match?

Comment: @BugFinder I haven't touched the EventSystem at all up to now. The tutorial I was viewing didn't make any changes to it (if im not mistaken). I also haven't touched Unity's input system, new or old.